# Equivalent of ModX chunks

Tags: cmsmadesimple

I'm looking for the equivalent of ModX's chunks in CMSMS. I've found Global Content but this doesn't appear to be what I want.

I want to be able to define some HTML, have it completely hidden from the end user editors that will be using the CMS to edit the site, and insert it into various templates like you can do with ModX's chunks.

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [User Defined Tags](http://wiki.cmsmadesimple.org/index.php/User_Handbook/Admin_Panel/Extensions/User_Defined_Tags).

They are PHP code blocks that you can use in your templates/global content blocks/content pages.

Comment: Thanks, I had found that a while ago.  i ended up using UDTs but you have to not give the user accounts that the client will be using access to use them.  They're not quite the same thing as chunks in ModX in that respect but can be used in such a way if needed.